# ASP.NET Web forms C# generating a Docx file from the fields the end-user fill up

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Good Day!

I want to create a asp.net web forms C# program that will generate a Docx file containing the data from fields the end-user fill up.

You see, I tried using NPOI but I don't see any tutorial that can help me about my case. I also use Power tools too, but sadly there is also no such thing that can help me.

Thank you so much in advance!

P.S My Sir said I cannot use an excel type file. It has to be a Docx type file.

Comment: Have you tried google? IF not try google "How programmatically create DOCX in C# using Document .Net library" and you will find an easy guide to follow.

Comment: @chrillelundmark yes Sir I have, and yet I still can't find any tutorial about it. At youtube there is also none. I just want Sir just a simple example about my case to open up the door in my mind(hehehe)

Comment: What about this link? [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/how-programmatically-0b9e250a)

Comment: @chrillelundmark yes Sir I saw that already, at first it help me to get started, but I still don't know what to do. I'm already using sautin soft as of the moment and looking for a tutorial or set of example codes to get me started on my program. Thank you so much sir for the effort. Appreciate it.